# Unable to use LOAD DATA INFILE | -secure-file-priv issue

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have tried many different possible solutions to resolve this issue but none seem to be fixing it for me.

I've tried solutions from other articles on here but none seem to be working

I am running **MySQL 8.0** (LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is not supported in this version)

Im trying to load data from a csv file into my tables by means of LOAD DATA INFILE. When I run the script, I receive this error:

> Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the
>   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

My code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'customer.csv'
INTO TABLE customer
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I have tried the following

- In the '' put the full directory of the file in different formats, including trying both / and \
- Remove the Secure-File-Priv from the config file
- Changed the directory to the folder on my Desktop
- Left the directory empty (Secure-File-Priv = "" {Also tried removing the ""})
- I checked the directory by running the query and it says it is where I have it set to on my Desktop

Is there anything else that I could try to load data into my tables or to get the Secure File Priv block removed?

### Update

This is the code with the error when the secure-file-priv is left empty:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/users/user/desktop/college/advanced db/uploads/customer.csv'
INTO TABLE customer
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

> Error Code: 29. File 'C:\users\carl\desktop\college\advanced
>   db\uploads\customer.csv' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute pathname as the filename parameter?

Comment: By this do you man putting the whole root? Eg C:\\Users\..

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. But now I see that you mentioned this in the first bullet.

Comment: You're getting the same error even with `secure-file-priv = ""`? Are you sure you restarted `mysqld` with that change?

Comment: Yes, I stopped the Server, made the change, closed mySql, started the server. Same error

Comment: That's very strange, setting it to an empty string is supposed to disable this check completely. What do you see if you do `select @@secure_file_priv;`?

Comment: When I run that it is blank. I will add my code at the bottom of the question with the output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Windows 7 or more:

1. Search "services" in the windows research table (left-down of the screen)
2. Search the Mysql service in the table and shut down it
3. Open the my.ini file (i assume "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\my.ini")
4. Search for Secure-File-Priv and assign "".
5. Restart the process via "services" or Mysql workbench
6. Put the .csv file into the directory of the database where exists the table (in this case "customer"), this is the possible path: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\.
7. Execute the query